# Стили речи

Tags: стилистика, стили-речи

Здравствуйте.  Какой из существующих в русском языке стилей речи считается наиболее правильным?      Спасибо. с уважением Юрий. Ещё раз, здравствуйте. Получается, что особенности речи  того или иного человека, или группы не относятся к предмету русского языка,а зависят от простой привычки, сформировавшейся у каждого в зависимости от особых свойств  воспитания, образования, быта и т д , присущих обществу, в котором развивается отдельный человек. Если я ошибаюсь, поправьте пожалуйста.  Большое спасибо....

Answer (score 6):

Правильный стиль тот, который уместен в данной ситуации. Неправильно было бы Президенту говорить из телевизора: "Хай, пипл!". Неправильно было бы приветствовать друзей на дискотеке: "Дорогие соотечественники!"

Answer (score 2):

Учение о трех стилях ввел Ломоносов – до него в русском литературном языке царила смесь различных языковых элементов как в лексике, так и в грамматике. По Ломоносову,  героические поэмы, оды,  трагедии должны быть написаны высоким стилем, стихотворные дружеские письма,  прозаические описания –  средним стилем, а комедии,  эпиграммы, песни, «описание обыкновенных дел», басни – низким стилем.

Стилевая характеристика текста (прежде всего, в области лексики и грамматики) очень важна  и в современном языке –  смешение  стилей всегда очень заметно и ОБЫЧНО говорит не в пользу автора.

В то же время такое смешение может являться художественным приемом, как, например, в произведениях Пушкина: Зима!.. Крестьянин, ТОРЖЕСТВУЯ, на дровнях  ОБНОВЛЯЕТ ПУТЬ.  «Именно тенденция пушкинского стиля к смешению церковнославянизмов, русских литературных и разговорно-бытовых слов составляет наиболее существенную сторону языкового новаторства поэта». Но для этого надо быть великим поэтом и иметь тонкий художественный вкус.

Comment: Если Александр Пушкин жил в эпоху рождения русского народа, тогда Александр Пушкин должен был смешивать "церковнославянизмы, русские литературные и разговорно-бытовые слова".

P.S. На самом деле, русский народ - очень молодой народ.

Answer (score 2):

Для каждого стиля существует своя речеая ситуация. Учитываются 3 показателя: с кем говоришь, в какой обстановке (офиц./неофиц.), с какой целью.